# How to use else if condition on click function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a ludo game, so I need if I click on any one box (say `r1`, `r2`, `r3`, `r4`) out of 4 boxes it should do the assigned work and after that, remaining 3 boxes remain constant (i.e don't do anything on click). I tried `else if` condition but its not working. Please help me out.

Here `r1`, `r2`, `r3` and `r4` are `id`s' of the boxes.

The thing I want to do:

```
if ($('#r1').click()) {
  $('#r1').click(function() {
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    $(this).animate((P[0]), 1000);
  });
} else if ($('#r2').click()) {
  $('#r2').click(function() {
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    $(this).animate((P[0]), 1000);
  });
} else if ($('#r3').click()) {
  $('#r3').click(function() {
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    $(this).animate((P[0]), 1000);
  });
} else if ($('#r4').click()) {
  $('#r2').click(function() {
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    $(this).animate((P[0]), 1000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".btn").on("click",function(){
    var _ID=this.id;
    if(_ID=="#r1")
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    else if(_ID=="#r2")
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
    else if(_ID=="#r3")
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
    else if(_ID=="#r4")
        $(this).css("background-color","blue");
        
    console.log(_ID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="#r1" class="btn">click1</button>
<button type="button" id="#r2" class="btn">click2</button>
<button type="button" id="#r3" class="btn">click3</button>
<button type="button" id="#r4" class="btn">click4</button>
```

Comment: Seems strange to have `#` in the IDs. Also, consider providing context.

Answer (score 0):

Let below be your `buttons` :

```
 <input id="r1" type="button" value="R1" />\
  <input id="r2" type="button" value="R2" />\
  <input id="r3" type="button" value="R3" />\
  <input id="r4" type="button" value="R4" />\
```

Then in your `jquery` write like below :

```
$(document).delegate("input[type='button']", "click",
    function(e){
    var clickbtn= this.id;//getting id of btn
        console.log("#"+clickbtn);
      //checking which btn is clicked
       if(clickbtn=="r1"){
        $("#"+clickbtn).css("position", "absolute");
         $("#"+clickbtn).animate((P[0]), 1000);
       }else if(clickbtn=="r2"){
        $("#"+clickbtn).css("position", "absolute");
         $("#"+clickbtn).animate((P[0]), 1000);
       }else if(clickbtn=="r3"){
       $("#"+clickbtn).css("position", "absolute");
         $("#"+clickbtn).animate((P[0]), 1000);

       }else{
        $("#"+clickbtn).css("position", "absolute");
         $("#"+clickbtn).animate((P[0]), 1000);
       }
});
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: i want that after clicking any one button it should animate but after that animation is done then after clicking on other one again it should not do the animation .

Comment: after clicking on same button you mean to say ,it should not animate?